# set priority in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and  need a logic.
Each dish in my table has a priority. see pic below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkYe5.jpg)
When I update the listing_priority from 3 to 1 where dishes_id is 4, it should also affect the remaining rows. ie. result should come as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX3zl.jpg)
Means priority should reset up and down automatically.

Hope I will get a help.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also paste what you trying to achieve in your post, not in images from external sources

Comment: Tried code plz?

Comment: @PatrickQ I assumed it meant Codeigniter, since people often abbreviate that "CI" and continuous integration is the first tag you get when you type ci

Comment: Regardless, this question needs some work before it can potentially be answerable. The description of the general situation is somewhat understandable, but it's really not clear what particular aspect of that is being asked about here.

Answer (score 0):

there are two conditions

if assignedPriority > currentPriority 
    then apply decrement on priority between(assignedPriority, currentPriority)
else
    apply increment on priority between(assignedPriority, currentPriority)

i think it will help